# Joining multiple tables in T-SQL and missing null rows for one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join 4 different tables, using full outer joins. Table 1 (calendar) only contains dates. Table 2(calls data) is joining the calendar date to date in table 2 with other call related data. Table 3 (gross sales) is joining date with table 1 & table 2 dates with other related data. Table 4 (paid sales) is also joining date with table 1 & table 2 dates with other related data.

My concern is I'm missing all the null values from Table 2. For example, Table 3 & 4 will have sales data, but Table 2 wont have the same sales & calls data because this particular sale was made online (no calls were involved)- so with my full outer joins I was expecting to have additional rows from Table 3 & Table 4 hence i was hoping my full outer joins would catch these but they don't! I have hit a brick wall with this. Example below:

```
cal_date    manager                        TID  user_signups    paid_sales  Calls
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6/1/2018    Online - PPC Social Facebook    4850        2               2           4
6/1/2018    Online - PPC Social Facebook    30355       1               1           1
6/1/2018    Online - PPC Social Facebook    31719       1               1           1
6/1/2018    Online - PPC Social Facebook    31717       1              NULL         1
6/1/2018    Online - PPC Social Facebook    31709       1               1           NULL
```

The last row above where there is sales information but NULL call information is what I want, but I'm not getting it in my results.

Any thoughts? Below is the query:

```js
declare @beg_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime
select @beg_date='2018-06-01'
select @end_date= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, current_timestamp))


--Table 1--
select c.cal_date,coalesce(s.manager,p.manager,m.Department) as manager, coalesce (s.campaign,p.campaign,m.aid) as TID, s.Retainer_Type,s.retainer_TUCT,s.user_signups,p.paid_sales,m.handles,m.volume,m.arrivals,m.total_abandons
from reporting.dbo.calendar c 


--Table 2--------
full outer join
(select cdv.row_date,
       vdns.Department,
       vdns.aid,     
sum(cdv.acdcalls) handles
,sum(cdv.acdcalls)+sum(cdv.abnquecalls)+sum(cdv.abnringcalls) volume, sum(cdv.i_arrived) arrivals, sum(cdv.abncalls) total_abandons
from CMS.dbo.dvdn cdv
left outer join (
              select vdn,
              case when CHARINDEX('.',tid)=0 then tid else left(tid,charindex('.',tid)-1) end aid,
              wtc.manager Department
              from AUSTRIA.cteam.tbl_phonenumbers ctp
              left join AUSTRIA.www_lexingtonlaw_com.tbl_campaigns wtc on case when CHARINDEX('.',ctp.tid)=0 then ctp.tid else left(ctp.tid,charindex('.',ctp.tid)-1) end=wtc.id
              where (case when CHARINDEX('.',tid)=0 then tid else left(tid,charindex('.',tid)-1) end<5000 or case when CHARINDEX('.',tid)=0 then tid else left(tid,charindex('.',tid)-1) end>=30000)
              and case when CHARINDEX('.',tid)=0 then tid else left(tid,charindex('.',tid)-1) end<>0
              and vdn<>0
              and vdn is not null
              and active=1
              and wtc.manager like 'Online - PPC%'
       union
              select vdn, assigned_campaign aid, wtc.manager Department
              from AUSTRIA.www_lexingtonlaw_com.dypr_phone_numbers dpr
              left join AUSTRIA.www_lexingtonlaw_com.tbl_campaigns wtc on wtc.id=dpr.assigned_campaign
              where assigned_campaign<>0
              and (assigned_campaign<5000 or assigned_campaign>30000)
              and vdn<>0
              and vdn is not null
              and active=1
              and wtc.manager like 'Online - PPC%'  
       ) vdns
       on cdv.vdn=vdns.vdn
where cdv.row_date between @beg_date and @end_date
and Department is not null
group by cdv.row_date, vdns.Department, vdns.aid) as m on c.cal_date = m.row_date



--Table 3--
full outer join(SELECT 
 wtr.yearmonthday
,cam.manager
,wtr.retainer_type
,wtr.campaign
,CASE WHEN wtr.TUCTS_Rank is null THEN '0' else wtr.TUCTS_Rank END as retainer_TUCT
,count(retainer_id) user_signups
       from Reporting.dbo.WLC_Tbl_Retainers wtr 
       inner join AUSTRIA.www_lexingtonlaw_com.tbl_campaigns cam
              on wtr.campaign = cam.id
       where core = 1
        and Entity_ID = 1
       and wtr.yearmonthday between @beg_date and @end_date
       and cam.manager like 'Online - PPC%'
group by 
 wtr.yearmonthday
,wtr.campaign
,wtr.retainer_type
,cam.manager
,CASE WHEN wtr.TUCTS_Rank is null THEN '0' else wtr.TUCTS_Rank END) as s on c.cal_date = s.yearmonthday and c.cal_date = m.row_date and s.Campaign = m.aid and s.manager = m.Department




--Table 4--
full outer join
(SELECT 
        kpi.yearmonthday
       ,kpi.campaign
       ,kpi.manager
       ,count(kpi.custnum) paid_sales
FROM REPORTING.Report.KPI_NEW_CustomersByMonth_LEX kpi 
where Status = 'New'
and kpi.upgradedowngrade_flag = 'N'
and kpi.ACTNUMBR_6 = 01
and kpi.manager like 'Online - PPC%'
and kpi.yearmonthday between @beg_date and @end_date
group by 
        kpi.yearmonthday
       ,kpi.campaign
       ,kpi.manager) as p  on c.cal_date = p.yearmonthday and p.yearmonthday = coalesce(m.row_date,c.cal_date) and m.aid = p.campaign and m.Department = p.manager
where c.cal_date between @beg_date and @end_date
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with. I would also suggest to simplify your query and only post whats relevant to your problem. We have no idea what is present in those tables

Comment: A common mistake is referring to a column from an `outer join` in a `where` clause without allowing for `NULL`. That effectively converts the `outer join` to an `inner join`. Whether that applies to the wall of code you posted is not obvious.

Comment: Kashif, thank you for your feedback. The above dataset contains sample data. The one with cal_data, manager etc.. cal_date comes from table 1, manager & TID is common in Table 2,3, and 4. While user signups come from table 3 & paid sales come from table 4. The last column which is "calls" comes from table 2. I know this must be confusing i apologize but i would highly appreciate your help here. The last row is what I should expect but im not getting it with my joins. The last row has cal_date of 6/1/2018 and has all the related data but NULL call data. I think my joins in table 2 are iffy

Comment: HABO, thank you so much for your feedback. So you are saying I should get rid of the where clauses in Table 2?

Comment: Since you haven't provided schemas for the tables and haven't consistently used aliases on columns, i.e. `ctp.tid`, we can't tell where the columns come from. If any of the columns referenced in the `where` clause of the `left outer join` are from the _right_ table then you need to allow for the possibility of the values being `NULL`. Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of an `outer join`. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.